# How to plot the alias frequency?

Tags: sampling, aliasing

I've been getting into sampling recently, and seem to have a problem with how to actually "plot" an alias frequency, and was hoping some of you might be able to help.

I have a sin-wave with an amplitude of 1 and a frequency of 3Hz. This means that when the "wave" have repeated itself 3 times you reach 1 second in time.

But now I got a sampling rate of 5Hz (for practicing aliasing), and in theory this would simply be sampleF - F => 5 - 3 = 2Hz. However, I'm not sure how I plot this 2Hz on my 3Hz signal? How should I "think" when plotting?

My plotting of 2Hz(Fsample - F = 2Hz) on a 3Hz signal:

[image]

Comment: The point of aliasing is that the 3 Hz signal will appear as a 2 Hz signal. So you plot it on your plot exactly as you would a 2 Hz signal.

Comment: is it correct that whenever you get a full number such as 2,3,4 etc, the new line will always just be a flat line? Because by the looks of it, my 2Hz signal should just be "flat".

Comment: Erik, I am not really sure what you mean. Maybe a picture or graph or something would help? If you do add a graph, the preferred way is to edit the question and add it there. If possible (there may be some restrictions on privilege for new users... not sure).

Comment: Updated my answer with an image. What am I doing wrong? (if it's wrong)

Comment: Hmmm. So the way to see it is to make a graph that has all of the following: 2 Hz signal, 3 Hz signal, and vertical lines at all sample points to show where signal will be sampled. The 2 Hz and 3 Hz signals will cross at all sample points.

Comment: Hmm, could you plot such a graph and show me? (always easier with graphics)
Currently my 2Hz signal does not really cross with my 3Hz signal? Or well, maybe when the 3Hz is done twice I get "6" and when 2Hz is done 3 times I get "6" as well, so I assume that is when they are to "meet". Still makes it flat tho (which might be the result anyway).

Comment: Hopefully someone else will answer. If not I will try to do it tomorrow. Meanwhile you can search for "aliasing examples" and see if that helps.

Comment: @ErikSvensson You have 21 divisions for 3 cycles, or 7 time divisions per cycle. Sampling at 5  Hz would be at 21/5 or 4.2 divisions per sample. Mark those on your paper. Then only look at what the marks show you.

Comment: How did you get 21 divisions for 3 cycles? I only got 12. Also my main problem is that I would need some kind of visual example to really "see it" I think, because even with the number of 4.2 divisions per sample with an alias frequency of 2, I'm not sure how to plot it on the paper.

Comment: For practice, it helps if you choose number other than fsamp=5 Hz, fsig = 2 Hz and 3 Hz, as then you get confused overlays. It's a lot easier to do this with a spreadsheet, and just as instructive as with pen and paper, more so as it doesn't make silly mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments to the question, the sampled points will be those points where 2Hz and 3Hz sinusoids will cross each other.

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) for aliasing has the figure you seek; but not for 3Hz and 2 Hz.

[Link to figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:AliasingSines.svg) The even have code for producing the figure it seems.

[Another figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Aliasing_between_a_positive_and_a_negative_frequency.svg)

Here is one I made with Octave. Initially it surprised me that the sampled points were NOT the points where the graphs were crossing each other. Then I realised that for the 2,3,5 combination, the *negative* frequency is getting aliased. So below you will find two sets of figures where 3Hz and 2Hz are plotted together and another set where 2Hz and *negated* 3Hz sinusoids are plotted together.

[image: aliasing figure]

Octave code for producing this figure.

```matlab
clear;

% a time vector with much much higher sampling frequency
% to represent the original continuous time signal.
time = [0 : 0.02 : 2]';

s3 = (-1) * sin(3*2*pi*time);
s2 = sin(2*2*pi*time);

% produces logical one at time period corresponding to 5Hz frequency
sample = abs(rem(time, 1/5))< 100*eps;

subplot(2,1,1);
% continuous time signal
plot(time, [s2,s3]);
hold on;

% samples
plot(time(sample), s2(sample), 'x', time(sample), s3(sample), '+');

legend('2Hz', '3Hz', '2Hz sampled', '3Hz sampled');
xlabel('time (s)');

subplot(2,1,2);
stem(time, sample);
legend('sampler');
xlabel('time (s)');
ylim([-1 2]);
```